# recalculating hierarchies in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that shows a hierarchy of some sort:

```
    SFID  SL    FID  L      Prob
1   N     L1    A    L0     1.000000
2   W     L3    A    L0     1.000000
6   Z     L2    N    L1     0.603842
10  M     L3    C    L0     0.485067
11  O     L3    B    L0     1.000000
12  X     L2    L    L2     0.600000
17  L     L2    C    L0     0.500000
20  P     L1    B    L0     0.400000
32  Y     L3    P    L1     0.900000
```

I want to generate all the SFIDs and FIDs that fall under every unique L0. As well as recalculate their probability. So for example, Prob( B -> Y ) = Prob(B -> P) * Prob(P -> Y)

So the final dataframe could look like this:

```
    SFID  FID   L   Prob
0   N     A     L0  1.000000
1   W     A     L0  1.000000
2   Z     A     L0  0.603842
3   O     B     L0  1.000000
4   P     B     L0  0.400000
5   Y     B     L0  0.360000
6   L     C     L0  0.500000
7   M     C     L0  0.485067
8   X     C     L0  0.300000
```

Comment: Does the hierarchy is one level only, like only A->N or A->N-Z, or can you get A->N->Z->Y->R->D too?

Comment: It goes from L0 to L3. So technically you can have A->N->X->Z and I would that to be A->N, A->X, A->Z